# Following a question

Tags: feature-request

Would be nice to be able to follow a question with a single click. Right now I use a workaround solution that takes a few clicks (if I can remember the way to do it at all)

Comment: Or there's the RSS feed at the bottom of every question page.

Comment: Maybe the feed icon should be moved under the favorite star... http://i.imgur.com/qhCBw.png

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty useful StackApps app called StackStalker (Google Chrome Extension) written by [Jason Edleman](http://www.jasonedelman.com/) that does exactly this (Including notification badges).  You can check it out here:

[StackStalker: Be Notified When Your Question Is Updated (Chrome Extension)](https://stackapps.com/questions/493/stackstalker-be-notified-when-your-question-is-updated-chrome-extension)

In Action:

[image: Following This Question]

After some changes:

[image: Got me a vote!]

Comment: thanks for the shoutout :)