# How to watch/follow interesting questions on SO?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Following a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86438/following-a-question)

Hi, I am big fan of SO and its community. I think I don't know the way to follow/watch few interesting questions on SO.

Say, someone asked a very good question and you would also like to know the answer/discussion related to this question. Earlier, I used to mark such questions as 'Favorite' by clicking on the Star icon next to the question, then SO used to show an enabled 'message' icon next to my login name in the top, if there is some discussion which happened on the question which I asked or a question which I marked as Favorite.

This was working fine till a change was made in the top bar showing a down arrow icon next to login name instead of the message icon.

Now I am not able to follow/watch the interesting questions. I mean, I am still able to "mark" for follow-up but not getting alerts related to new activity on those questions.

Could you please help me know the new way to follow/watch questions in SO?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's always the RSS feed for each question. There's a link at the bottom right of the page.

Comment: @ChrisF I think you should post this as answer

Comment: @dep_stats - I'm fairly sure that this question is a duplicate, but can't find it right now.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF! But I feel rather than following RSS feed for all those Favorite questions, the earlier implementation of message icon glowing when there is a response, was better. Earlier SO was alerting me when there is a new message, now I will have to pull all that information.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChrisF stated there is always the RSS feed. However in the new drop down the word "Favorites" is a link to the listing of your favored question activities.

Comment: Thanks Dustin! But then following each of those questions' RSS feed is not so convenient. IMHO, the earlier implementation of message glowing icon just before the login name in the top bar was better. We can discuss this more here in this meta forum.