# Following Stack Overflow questions

Tags: support, bookmarks, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Following a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86438/following-a-question)

Is there a way to 'follow' any question asked at Stack Overflow? By follow I mean get notifications when relevant events have occurred regarding a specific question, e.g. a new answer was poster, editor changed the question formulation or an answer was accepted.

Quite often I find myself browsing through questions, encountering a few I do not know the answer to, but would like to find out. But the next time I log in, the questions are far gone from 'Top questions', and I can only find the using the search functionality - in which case I must remember all those questions I wanted the answer to - not likely.

I can't seem to find any similar feature. If there indeed is none, could this perhaps be considered as a feature request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an RSS feed for each question e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/7877351

Use a decent reader on your mobile device to get push notifications.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, Matt Ball's answer is also good, depending on what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You can ["Favorite" the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) by clicking the hollow star icon below the up/downvote arrows.